# Oversampling irreguler time series

Tags: python, time-series, sampling

I have a time series data from a motion sensor, the sampling frequency is about 200 [Hz] (i.e. the time intervals between the samples has a mean of 45 [ms] with a standard deviation of 0.5 [ms], so it's not evenly spaced perfectly).
There are markers every 6 seconds in the data.

I also have a second time series with a sampling frequency of 5000 [Hz], and the same markers at exactly the same times.

I need the first time series to be over-sampled to the same sampling frequency of the second time series. With the markers being in the exact point. The goal is to be able to align the 2 time series together.

P.S.
I tried looking for packages that can regulate the samples then over-sample them, but I couldn't find any straight forward answer.

Thank you.

edit:
An example data, this is from the first data set, duration is 9 seconds, it should be over-sampled to a sampling frequency of 5000 [Hz].

http://txt.do/dk4ne

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: I added a link to an example of the data.